# Format datetime_local_field rails form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, format

So i have a form with field: datetime_local_field

```
= datetime_local_field :invitation, :date
```

Witch returns datetime input with format: mm/dd/yyyy, --:-- --(AM, PM).

My question is, how does one set format to this field(I want to use 24-hour system.)

P.S

I tried:

```
= datetime_local_field :invitation, :date, format: '..Put format here..'
```

No success.

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: I am not sure but can you try something like this `f.datetime_local_field :invitation, html: { value: f.object.invitation.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M") }`

Comment: Tried it, no success...

Comment: Did you set a default locale for your application in application.rb?

Comment: config.i18n.default_locale = :en

Comment: = f.datetime_local_field :date, value: invitation.date.to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

This shows the corrent date in format, but this type if datepicker is not supported by firefox AND it uses your browsers default date format(witch is not editable).

Thanks for responses.